# Why pytest always says " ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Tags: python, import, pytest

I'm new to pytest and python. My project structure is :

```
projroot/
|-src/
  |-a.py
|-test/
  |-test_a.py
```

and test_a.py is:

```py
from ..src import a
def test_a():
  pass
```

Then run `pytest`under `projroot`:

```
projroot>pytest
```

And always there is the error info: `E   ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.
Python verison: 3.8 on windows 10 x64.
I read a lot articles and blogs and [official suggestions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html), but still failed to figure out. Help me, please!

Comment: You need to add (possibly empty) `__init__.py` files so that Python knows these are packages. At least one in `src`, perhaps also in `test` and possibly in `projroot` too. That should solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you, filbranden and napuzba! Solved! I found `__init__.py`files are essential in `test` and `projroot`, but not in `src`.

Answer (score 25):

I found I must add `__init__.py` in `test` and `projroot`. `__init__.py` in `src` is not necessary. 
And `pytest` could run correctly in 3 folders:

```py
# parent folder of project root
C:\>pytest projroot

# project root
C:\>cd projroot
C:\projroot>pytest

# test folder
C:\projroot>cd test
C:\projroot\test>pytest
```

Answer (score 9):

Adding `__init__.py` to project root actually messed up my pytest discovery and also pylint (causing `Unable to import 'angles' pylint(import-error)`). I had to remove it from project root and only add it inside my tests folder, which solved both my pytest discovery and pylint warning.

With `__init__.py` in project root, i'll have `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'angles'`

Below is my folder structure with both pytest discovery and pylint (without warning) working :

```
powerfulpython
├── angles.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_angles.py
```

In angles.py I have a `Class Angle` which I try to absolute import using `from angles import Angle` inside `test_angles.py`.

Before I found out that the issue was having an unnecessary `__init__.py` in project root. I also tried

1. editing `python.testing.cwd`
2. setting '--rootdir' of pytest
3. Downgrading Python extension to 2020.9.114305 (following https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14579)

None of them worked.

Before i deleted the `__init__.py` in project root, when testing pytest, doing `python -m pytest` worked because the project root is prepended to sys.path automatically so the absolute import was working correctly from root and the import statement can find `angles` under root. Doing `pytest` (without python -m) fails because the project root is not prepended to sys.path. The latter can be temporarily solved by adding the root directory manually to $PYTHONPATH. However this is an unsustainable solution as I don't want to add every single new project i want to test as a PYTHONPATH edit to my ~/.zshrc.

Another hack I tried which fixed both `pytest` and test discovery was inserting `sys.path.insert(0,'/Users/hanqi/Documents/Python/powerfulpython')`  in the code but this is way too ugly. I didn't want to add lines to code just for testing then have to delete them later.

After all these, I deleted `__init__.py` in root and all's good.
No need for any of the above list of 3 items.

Many solutions I went through deal with finding the tests folder, but that was not my problem. My tests were found correctly in their folders, just that the `from angles import Angle` was breaking which causes test discovery to fail.

**Investigating how does `__init__.py` in project root break things:**

I printed sys.path and realized with it, `~/Documents/Python` got prepended to sys.path and without it, `~/Documents/Python/powerfulpython` got prepended. The latter path is exactly my project root.
I'm guessing this has something to do with https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/pythonpath.html (`--import-mode=prepend` (default)).
I was expecting to see the `__init__.py` inside `tests` to cause `~/Documents/Python/powerfulpython` to be prepended and the `__init__.py` in project root cause `~/Documents/Python` to be prepended, but strangely i only saw the latter when I left both  `__init__.py` inside.

I also tried deleting the `__init__.py` inside `tests` (but let `__init__.py` in root stay), and see `~Documents/Python/powerfulpython/tests` prepended to sys.path. This same line is also prepended if I delete both `__init__.py` in root and tests, not sure why.

**Edit:**
The above behaviour is explained at https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/pythonpath.html

*It will then search upwards until it can find the last folder which still contains an `__init__.py` file in order to find the package root*

After further repeating my above experiments running using `python -m pytest -s` (-s so successful test runs don't swallow my `print(sys.path)`) instead of just `pytest`, I confirm that there are 2 actors prepending to sys.path.

1. `python -m` (what it prepends depends on from which directory the command is run)
2. `pytest` (what it prepends depends on where are `__init__.py` inserted (explained in pytest docs linked above)

Both have the effect of editing sys.path, helping to make failing imports possible

Jacques Yang above needed 2 `__init__.py` to put the containing folder of his projroot into sys.path so `projroot.test` appears as the value of `__package__` in his `test_a.py` and `__name__` would appear as `projroot.test.test_a`, and the 2 dots in this module name (`__name__`) allow the two dot relative import of `from ..src import a`. He could also have used an absolute import of `from projroot.src import a`.

If he didn't add the `__init__.py` in projroot, the `__package__` would become just `test` and `__name__` would be `test.test_a`, which would only allow an upwards relative step of at most 1 step. (This stepping concept is also explained by BrenBarn at [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)).

When there is `__init__.py` in `test` but not `projroot`, that would have been `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`, because `__package__` is `test` and `__name__` is `test.test_a` allowing only 1 step back up but 2 steps back was coded.
The question in the title occurs when there isn't even `__init__.py` in `test`, so `__package__` is completely blank and `__name__` is only the `test_a` file itself)

I was thinking why did OP need 2 `__init__.py` while I only needed 1, and 2 actually harms my attempt. Then I realized OP was doing relative import and I was doing absolute import with `from angles import Angle`. If i followed OP's pattern and did relative import `from ..angles import Angle`, then I also would have needed to add `__init__.py` under `powerfulpython`, otherwise i'll get the same errors.

So why does doing absolute import break with the extra `__init__.py` in `~/Documents/Python/powerfulpython`? Because the `__init__.py` causes pytest to step up even higher in the hierarchy and prepend `~/Documents/Python` to sys.path, but my absolute import needed to have `~/Documents/Python/powerfulpython` (this can be resolved with running using `python -m pytest` as explained in the 2 actors of prepending section above, but feels somewhat unnatural compared to simply `pytest`)

I have a 30-min demo video on import concepts at https://towardsdatascience.com/taming-the-python-import-system-fbee2bf0a1e4 that could help people understand `__package__` and `__name__`.

Answer (score 7):

By including a setup.py file in  root directory and init.py in every folder worked for me and for importing a package inside any file just give that package location from parent directory

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name="PACKAGENAME", packages=find_packages())
```

```
projroot/
|-__init__.py
|-setup.py
|-src/
  |-a.py
  |-__init__.py
|-test/
  |-test_a.py
  |-__init__.py
```

```
from src import a
def test_a():
  pass
```

Reference
https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/goodpractices.html